# Bootstrap, Sidebar Not Responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use twitter bootstrap for my project and I place sidebar at right side, but when I change resolution, it wont come as same as other resolution. Here and attach two screen shots for resolution 1024 and 1366 both are with 768 (1024 x 768 and 1366 x 768). and also I copy my css code for this. (Main code is very complicated so I unable to put it on jsfiddle)

```
    .div.panel
{
    display: none;
    z-index: 3;
    top: 201px;
    right: 9%;
    height: auto;
}
.catlogsidepanel 
{
    width: 300px;
    float: right;
    background: url(../images/bg_sidepannel.png) repeat-y;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 400px;
}
```

I use **right: 9%** for set right side position.

**1024 x 768**

[image]

**1366 * 768 (This is correct, I want this in 1024 resolution)**

[image]

Comment: Make sure to add a class or id identifier on your css.

Comment: I'm new in CSS and designing in HTML, Can you please tell me How to do that ?

Comment: Currently as show on your code, your using a class without '.' or '#'. Make sure to add it.

`.catlogspanel{ }`

Comment: @janharold sorry i forgot to place this in my code here but its all-ready placed on my actual code.

Comment: Is that an ligthbox/overlay (triggered by clicked by JS)? Also, it will never be the same since you're currently using the browser width which is changes value. You should include it inside a container. It would be much more better if we see the code live.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing class or id identifier in `catlogsidepanel` . It should be either `.catlogsidepanel` or `#catlogsidepanel`.

Comment: No, I user only CSS for this, there is no jquery for that.

Comment: No. I copy that code from Google Chrome's Console so it want display but it is all-ready typed.